# why I need to use std::decay in the following case?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I am a newbie in C++ and made a test program to learn more about `decltype`, `std::decay`, `std::is_same_v`(traits) and also `typeid`.

I have following simple class, in which I wanted to get the template parameter type `Type` in the `Base` class's constructor using `decltype`.

like `decltype(content of std::vector<Type>::iterator::begin)`. Some how, it did not work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <typeindex>

template<typename Type> class Base
{
    std::vector<Type> vec;
public :
    Base(std::initializer_list<decltype(*vec.begin())> liVec): vec(liVec) {}
    // here                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ . isn't enough?? 
};

int main()
{
    //Base<int> obj{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };     // does not works: error !

    // to see the type, I wrote the following code
    std::vector<int> vec;
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(*vec.begin())).name() << std::endl; // prints i means int type(I know not reliable though)
    // and
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same_v<int, decltype(*vec.begin())> << std::endl; // prints false 

    return 0;
}
```

The error on the line `Base<int> obj{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };` was(in GCC 6.1, C++14)

```
include\c++\initializer_list||In instantiation of 'class std::initializer_list<int&>':|
include\c++\initializer_list|54|error: forming pointer to reference type 'int&'|
include\c++\initializer_list|55|error: forming pointer to reference type 'int&'|
main.cpp|17|error: no matching function for call to 'Base<int>::Base(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'|
candidate: 'Base<Type>::Base(std::initializer_list<decltype (*((Base<Type>*)(void)0)->Base<Type>::vec.begin())>) [with Type = int; decltype (*((Base<Type>*)(void)0)->Base<Type>::vec.begin()) = int&]'|
main.cpp|11|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 5 provided|
main.cpp|7|note: candidate: 'Base<int>::Base(const Base<int>&)'|
main.cpp|7|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 5 provided|
main.cpp|7|note: candidate: 'Base<int>::Base(Base<int>&&)'|
main.cpp|7|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 5 provided|
```

As I saw the compiler told me something about `int&`, I simply tried it with following.(i.e, `std::decay_t`) and it worked.

```
template<typename Type> class Base
{
    std::vector<Type> vec;
public :
    Base(std::initializer_list<std::decay_t<decltype(*vec.begin())>> liVec): vec(liVec) {}
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ why I need this here?
};

int main()
{
    Base<int> obj{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };     // works now

    std::vector<int> vec;
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(*vec.begin())).name() << std::endl; // prints i means int type(not reliable though)
    // and
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same_v<int, std::decay_t<decltype(*vec.begin())>> << std::endl; // true now: WHY?

    return 0;
}
```

**But I don't know the meaning of the error and why it worked. Could someone explain me what exactly happend?**

Comment: `typeid` does not care about reference or const qualifiers of types, so even if you see `i`, it might be `int`, `const int`, `int &`, `const int&`, and so on.

Comment: @Holt Oh.. that makes sence. Then it looks like `typeid` is not really usful in any cases. isn't it?

Comment: `typeid` gives you a `std::type_info`, which in turns can give you a `std::type_index` which can be use as key in associative container, so this can be used to map "type" to whatever you want. This may have some use in specific cases.

Comment: @KillzoneKid But I made it for `begin()`.

Comment: @KillzoneKid Okay. Then now I am really confused. The above case might happen when I use `Base<int> obj{ };`, I guess.

Comment: @KillzoneKid Whatever is inside `decltype` is an *unevaluated operand*, so this is not UB.

Comment: @KillzoneKid That looks good and more safer than iterator use. But does not compiles with template where I wanted to use.

Comment: @Const Whatever is inside `decltype` is never evaluated, so as long as the expression is syntactically valid, you can do whatever you want. `decltype(vec)::value_type` should work, as long as the types you are using have `value_type` member (which is the case for all standard containers).

Comment: @Holt, I believe you are right `int i = 10; decltype(++i);` i is still 10, thanks for mentioning this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first line of your error messages says (among other things):

```
instantiation of 'class std::initializer_list<int&>'
```

So it is trying to create an *initializer_list* with a *reference type* which is not allowed.

Looking at your template code you have:

```
 std::initializer_list<decltype(*vec.begin())>
```

Now `vec.begin()` yields an *iterator* and dereferencing an *iterator* yields a *reference* so you can do things like:

```
*iter = whatever;
```

So you need to remove the *reference* part of the type. [std::decay_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) does that.

Comment: so you mean `*vec.begin()` is equal to `Type&` in this case??

Comment: @Const Yes, it is.

Comment: if so `std::remove_reference` will also do the same job of `std::decay`. Just want to understand.

Comment: @Const `std::decay` does a lot of stuff, including removing reference as `std::remove_reference` would do. You can read a bit more here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay, and also have a look at the "possible implementation" section to see what it actually does.

Comment: Okay. I need more readings. meanwhile you have cleared my qestion. Thanks a lot. ;)